# Set API key with embed API google analytics

Tags: google-maps, google-analytics, google-visualization, google-analytics-api, api-key

I was rending map with my google analytics data using embed api as:

```
    (function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
      g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
      js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
      fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
    }(window,document,'script'));

    gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
       serverAuth: {
           access_token: 'my access token' 
        }
    )};

    var commonConfig2 = {
       query: {
           ids: 'ga:' + gaViewId,
           metrics: 'ga:users',
           dimensions: 'ga:region',
           'max-results': 5,
           sort : '-ga:users'   
        },
           chart: {
           type: 'GEO',
           container: 'timeline',
           options: {
              displayMode: 'markers',
              width: '100%' 
           }
        }
    };

    var dataChart3 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart(commonConfig2)
          .set({query: dateRange1})
          .set({chart: {container: 'chart-3-container'}});
```

Map was rendering fine. But few days back i got error "Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError" and map is no longer rending. After some googling i came to know that google now require Api key to access its api. How can i set api key with my existing code.

Comment: You know I am not all that sure you can.  I am thinking its built into the Embeded API.   I am going to ping Google on this, see if they respond might take a while they are west cost USA.

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo will be waiting.

Comment: don't use analytics, so i'm guessing this doesn't apply? --> [Specify a key when loading the api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#specify-a-key-when-loading-the-api)

Comment: @WhiteHat post editted please check how gapi is initialized. not able to set key.

Comment: ??? --> [`gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey)`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiclientsetapikeyapikey)

Comment: tried this before and after  gapi.analytics.auth.authorize but no luck.

Comment: Hey @DaImTo Any luck?

Comment: Yup the Analytics team is looking at it.  Current consensus is that the Maps API changed something that broke embedded.    They are looking into it I will let you know when I hear more.

Comment: Maps has changed something API Key is now required.  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key  waiting to hear if the GA team has any way around it.   The project isnt open source so its not something we can fix we need them to fix it.

Comment: Any update @DaImTo ?

Comment: Yup no one is working on the embedded API so they cant say when or if it will ever be fixed.  You cant fix it yourself its not open source.  So basically its broken until further notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This took a little emailing back and forth with the team at Google.

It appears that the Maps API has changed and now requires that you send an key to access it.

The embedded API was not designed to allow you to send a key it assumed that one was not needed.

**Status:** At this time no one is working on the Embedded API and the code for it is not open source.   Maps in the Embedded API are broken until further notice. My Google contact was unable to tell me when or if it would be fixed in the future.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed the same issue today, after many attemps and no documentation I've got it working again!

Here is what you need to do:

1. Go to https://console.developers.google.com, select your project and enable on it the **[Google Maps Geocoding API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/geocoding_backend/)** and the **[Google Maps JavaScript API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/maps_backend/)** (for the second one, keep note of the *API_KEY* and set your allowed referrer urls);
2. In your sources, ensure to import the following scripts:

   ```
   <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"></script>
   ```

That's all, now your Embed API maps will restart to draw the location data with no errors or warnings.
It would be better if that was written on Google Analytics Embed API documentation (as of now, it has been also removed the map sample on the [website](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/))